# Android app crashes after publishing on Play Store?

Tags: java, android, crash, proguard

I have done big update for my app, and everything is working fine when I run app with Android Studio, but when I published it to Play Store it crashes instantly on most devices. (It's working on some older android devices).

I tried to disable minify and ProGuard to avoid proguard making some classes invisible, but still crash. Also I tried to sign release apk and transfer it via USB to phone. After installing it's working perfectly, and after uploading the same APK file to to Play Store - it crashes. Help pls

*note: I lowered minSdk from 21 to 16, and enabled multiDex. Can multiDex cause crash?

Edit: Crash report from Play Console

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3844)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3884)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3053)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1777)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6861)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:450)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
      at com.lampa.SaVaVoiceRecorder.activities.RecordingActivity.onResume (RecordingActivity.java:825)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume (Instrumentation.java:1355)
      at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:7218)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3819)
```

Comment: Have you checked crash report in Google Play Console ?

Comment: Please send your chash report

Comment: you have to get the crash stacktrace. There are a lot of ways to do that, use one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: After inspecting Play Console report, I found `java.lang.NullPointerException` in `onResume` method, but this make no sense. Everything is written good and app is working perfectly if it's not downloaded from Play Store.

Comment: To know the problem, you need to check to which line of code it refers. Since you did not post neither stacktrace nor code - good luck doing it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you protect your app in **[Protect Appeals](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)** and then `unistall apk(debug mode)` from android devices before install apk(release mode).

Comment: I don't think this is a solution, because there are a lot of users installing and running app just fine. But on my testing Galaxy S9 and Huawei p20 it's working fine when it's local installed, but crash after installing from Play Store. Tried on few more s9 and s8, still crash after Play Store install. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, running fine in VS but crashing once published to play store.  I changed the build and version number and published the exact same code and the issue was resolved.